# Как запустить 2 декоратора одновременно?

Tags: python, многопоточность, telebot, бот, telethon

Нужно чтобы одновременно работало 2 обработчика. От telebot `get_text_messages(message):` и telethon `normal_handler(event)`.

В исходном коде ниже исправно работает только обработчик бота, так как он стоит первый, естественно второй обработчик не запустится пока первый не закончит свою работу.

Я не сведущий в потоках и асинхронности опробовал оба варианта и естественно ничего не заработало должным образом. Так как всё таки заставить работать их одновременно?

````
import os
import time, datetime
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import json
import telebot
import sys

command = ["Чтобы посчитать часы за последний день: /Count_time_today",
"Чтобы получить часы за всё время введите: /Count_time_all",
"Чтобы получить часы за конкретный период введите даты по шаблону: /count dd.mm.yyyy-dd.mm.yyyy",
]


client = TelegramClient('SELF', api_id, api_hash)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


def getid_dialog():
    """Возвращает id диалога"""
    for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        if dialog.name == "DataWork":
            return dialog.id

def is_time_full(arg):
        """Принимает строку типа '11:17-19:16'(str).
        Возвращает True если время записано в нужном виде"""
        try:
            arg = arg.replace('-',':')
        except:
            result = False
        arg = arg.split(':')
        if len(arg) == 4:
            for a in arg:
                if a.isdigit():
                    if (arg.index(a)+1)%2 != 0:
                        if int(a) <= 24:
                            return True
                    elif (arg.index(a)+1)%2 == 0:
                        if int(a) <= 59:
                            return True
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    return False      
        else:
            return False



def is_date(arg):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(arg, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
        return True
    except:
        return False
                    

def correct_message(message):
    """Принимает объект сообщения телеграм, а возвращает True если данные в норме"""
    mass = [False, False]
    if message.message != None:
        for i in message.message.split(" "):
                if is_time_full(i):
                    mass[0] = True
                elif is_date(i):
                    mass[1] = True
                else:
                    return False
        if ((mass == [True, True]) or (mass == [True, False])):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def right_note(message):
    """Принимает объект сообщения телеграм и определяет дату в тексте сообщения,
     возвращает новую структуру сообщения для записи в базу данных, где дата из текста сообщения
    заменяет дату объекта."""
    new_message = []
    new_date = False
    for i in message.message.split(" "):
        if is_date(i):
            new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d.%m.%Y").date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        elif is_time_full(i):
            new_message.append(i)
    if not new_date:
        new_date = message.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    new_message = " ".join(new_message)
    minutes = count_time(new_message)
    return {"id":message.id, "message":new_message, "message_date":new_date, 'minutes':minutes}

        
def sorted_date_in_right_notes(mass_right_notes):
    return sorted(mass_right_notes,key=lambda x: x['message_date'])


extract = lambda x,y: x[x.index(y)]['message']

def count_time(arg):
    sum_min = 0
    for i in arg.split(' '):
        left = i.split('-')[0].split(':')
        right = i.split('-')[1].split(':')
        if int(right[0]) == 0:
            right[0] = '24'
        Left_minutes = int(left[0])*60+int(left[1])
        right_minutes = int(right[0])*60+int(right[1])
        difference_min = right_minutes - Left_minutes
        sum_min += difference_min
    return sum_min


path = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0],'DataWork.json')
client.start()
if not os.path.isfile(path):
    with open(path,'w', encoding='utf-8') as db:
        id_dialog = getid_dialog()
        mass_messages = []
        for message in client.iter_messages(id_dialog):
            if correct_message(message):
                mass_messages.insert(0, right_note(message))
        mass_messages = sorted_date_in_right_notes(mass_messages)
        json.dump(mass_messages, db)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == '/help':
        bot.send_message(439522950, "\n".join(command))
    elif message.text == "/Count_time_today":
        mass_messages = reopen_data(path)
        minutes = f"{mass_messages[-1]['minutes']//60}ч. {mass_messages[-1]['minutes']%60}мин."
        bot.send_message(439522950, minutes)
    elif message.text == "/Count_time_all":
        mass_messages = reopen_data(path)
        summ = 0
        for i in mass_messages:
            summ += int(i['minutes'])
        summ = f"{summ//60}ч. {summ%60}мин."
        bot.send_message(439522950, summ)
    elif message.text[:6] == '/count':
        mass_messages = reopen_data(path)
        period_date = message.text[6:].strip()
        left_date = period_date.split("-")[0]
        right_date = period_date.split("-")[1]
        try:    
            left_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(left_date, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
            right_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(right_date, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
        except:
            bot.send_message(439522950, "Не правильный формат ввода.")
        for i in mass_messages:
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(i['message_date'],"%Y-%m-%d").date() >= left_date:
                first_date = mass_messages.index(i)
                break

        for i in mass_messages:
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(i['message_date'],"%Y-%m-%d").date() >= right_date:
                second_date =  mass_messages.index(i)
                break
        
        new_mass_messages = mass_messages[first_date:second_date+1]
        summ = 0
        for i in new_mass_messages:
            summ += int(i['minutes'])
        summ = f"{summ//60}ч. {summ%60}мин."
        bot.send_message(439522950, summ)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=20)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=getid_dialog()))
def normal_handler(event):
    if event.message.message == 'exit':
        exit() 
    if correct_message(event.message):
        with open(path,'r', encoding='utf-8') as db:
            mass_messages = json.load(db)
            mass_messages.append(right_note(event.message))


        with open(path, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as db:
            json.dump(mass_messages, db)
client.run_until_disconnected()```
````

Comment: Не нужно включать весь код в вопрос. Без ущерба для вопроса (и с большой пользой и для других, кто будет искать ответ и для того, кто захочет ответить) можно удалить 95% кода из вопроса и оставить маленький пример, в котором будут всего лишь два практически пустых обработчика (возможно с вызовом `sleep` для эмуляции задержки) и код для запуска бота. `опробовал оба варианта и естественно ничего не заработало` - значит что-то делали не так, но что именно без кода, мы не подскажем.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вас будут помнить и чтить целые поколения